# Form is not submit when click on modal button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form on modal when I click on modal update button then its happen nothing.

Here is my modal code

```js
$("#TypeValidation").on('submit', (function(e) {
    alert('enter');
    var reference = $(this).find('input[name="reference"]').val();
    var valid_date = $(this).find('input[name="valid_date"]').val();
    var description = $(this).find('select[name="description"]').val();
    var attachment = $(this).find('input[name="attachment"]').val();
    var Update_taskid = $(this).find('button[name="Update_task"]').val();
    if (description && reference && valid_date)

    {

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../controllers/authentication_function.php?Update_taskid=" + Update_taskid,
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#Update_task").prop('disabled', 'disabled')
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
                if (result == '1') {
                    location.replace("lst_tasks.php");

                } else {
                    location.replace("lst_tasks.php");

                }
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editTasks_<?php echo $Row[$data]->id;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
</div>
<form id="TypeValidation" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group has-label">
         <label>
         Reference
         </label>
         <input class="form-control" name="reference" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 form-group has-label">
         <label>
         Expiry Date of file
         </label>
         <input class="form-control datepicker" name="valid_date" type="text">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group has-label">
         <label>
         File Upload
         </label><br>
         <div class="fileinput fileinput-new text-center" data-provides="fileinput">
            <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail"></div>
            <div>
               <span class="btn btn-rose btn-round btn-file">
               <span class="fileinput-new">Select File</span>
               <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
               <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
               </span>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-round fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group has-label">
         <label>
         Description
         </label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <div class="pull-left">
      <button type="submit" value="Update_task" name="Update_task" id="Update_task" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
   </div>
   <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is authentication_function.php code

```
  <?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['Update_taskid']) && ($_REQUEST['Update_taskid']=="Update_task")){
    global $con;

         $reference = base64_encode($_REQUEST['reference']);
         $valid_date = $_REQUEST['valid_date'];
         $description = base64_encode($_REQUEST['description']);
         $cdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
         $status = 1;

          //Task File  UPLOAD
         if ($_FILES['attachment']['name']!=""){
             if($_FILES['attachment']['size'] >= 1048576) {
                print "<font color='#CC0000' size='+1' style='font:bold'><strong>Image Size Out of Bound.</strong></font>";
                break;
             }

        $filePath="../uploads/task_files/";
        $file = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $filePath.$file);

        }
         else {$file=$_SESSION['file1']; unset($_SESSION['file1']);}
                       $update_task = array("reference"=>$reference,"valid_date"=>$valid_date,"description"=>$description,"attachment"=>$file,"cdate"=>$cdate,"status"=>$status);
        $table = tbl_task_activities;

        $UpdateTask = InsertDB($update_task, $table);

        if ($UpdateTask!=''){
            $_SESSION['update_task']="update_msg";
            echo 1;
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['error_update_task']="update_error_msg";
            echo 0;
                }
            }
          ?>
```

I tried it, cannot fix my error. plaese tell me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: I edited and added a snippet. It looks like your form is submitting.

Comment: Jquery is missing from your code. It is working after adding it.

Comment: @RogerC okey I am checking on my browser its working or not

Comment: I added jQuery in the snippet. As @Rohit.007 said, it may be missing in your HTML page.

Comment: @RogerC still its not working on my browser

Comment: @RogerC can you post it code below?

Comment: This is the first line of the HTML part of the snippet. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I think that jquery is not a problem because I am using jquery

Comment: Ok. It was just missing from the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I think this will help you to submit form.

```
<script type="text/javscript">
$(function(){
     //form submit code here   
      $("#TypeValidation").on('submit', (function(e) {
          alert('enter');
       });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and found that there is only one mistake which creating an issue:

changed select[name="description"] to below

```
 var description = $(this).find('textarea[name="description"]').val();
```

because you have textarea for a description

```
 <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
```

Also move `e.preventDefault();` at first line

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#TypeValidation").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

It will work!!

Comment: now its still not working after this error and I cannot get alert enter after click on update button

Comment: You also need to put  e.preventDefault();  after $("#TypeValidation").on('submit', (function(e) {. I mean at first line

Comment: Look at the above solution. The document must first be in the ready-state

Comment: I tried it all answer code but still not showing me alert error on chrome broswer

Comment: Please update your scripts with the current solution